# Como criar perfil de administrador a partir desse código?

Tags: java, jsp, autenticação

Como criar um perfil de administrador a partir desse código, e ao logar que seja feita uma verificação se é um usuário comum ou um administrador?

DaoUsuario.java

```
package br.edu.facema.model.dao;

import br.edu.facema.model.bean.Usuario;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DaoUsuario {

public Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "123");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}

public Usuario getUsuario(String login, String senha) {
    Connection c = this.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        ps = c.prepareStatement("select id, nome from usuario where login = ? and senha = ?");
        ps.setString(1, login);
        ps.setString(2, senha);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            Usuario user = new Usuario();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setLogin(login);
            user.setSenha(senha);
            user.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));

            return user;

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;
            }
            rs = null;
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;
            }
            ps = null;
        }
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;
            }
            c = null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}

package br.edu.facema.model.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private int id;

private String nome;

private String login;

private String senha;

private int tipoUsuario;

public int getTipoUsuario() {
    return tipoUsuario;
}

public void setTipoUsuario(int tipoUsuario) {
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
}

public int getId() {

    return id;

}

public void setId(int id) {

    this.id = id;

}

public String getLogin() {

    return login;

}

public void setLogin(String login) {

    this.login = login;

}

public String getNome() {

    return nome;

}

public void setNome(String nome) {

    this.nome = nome;

}

public String getSenha() {

    return senha;

}

public void setSenha(String senha) {

    this.senha = senha;

}

}
```

Comment: O próprio JSP não tem nenhum recurso de sessão ou autenticação? Seria legal usar algo padrão do que reinventar a roda.

Comment: É um trabalho da faculdade, pra questão de aprendizado.

Comment: Então o mais facil seria implementar uma classe Administrador, que herda as caracteristicas de Usuario, e verificar na própria pagina, se o usuario que estiver chegando não for da instancia de Administrador, redireciona a pagina. Acredito que seria o mais facil. Ou para ficar melhor na elaboração, criar uma interface Pessoa, que facilitaria na hr da verificação, já que tanto usuario quanto administrador implementariam essa interface.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Faça mais um deste modelo, por exemplo "Administrador", permitindo que tenha acesso a ele.

```java
boolean permite;
public void autentifica(DaoUsuario user, DaoAdministrador admin) {
    if (permite) {
        user.Usuario(login,senha);
    } else {
        admin.Administrador(login,senha);
    }
}
```